# How to use applescript to tell Mail to keep a copy of sent message

Tags: email, applescript

I use AppleScript and can send messages without any problem, but the "Sent" box does not get a copy of what I sent. However, if I use Mail Application to send messages, the "Sent" box gets a copy of what I sent. So I guess my AppleScript may miss a command or so to tell Mail to keep a copy of the sent messages. What's the command that I missed? Thanks.

```
tell application "Mail"                                                         
    set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}                       
    tell theNewMessage                                                          
        set visibile to false                                                   
        set sender to theSender                                                 
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}                                                                     
        make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after the last paragraph                                                              
        send                                                                    
        delay 5                                                                 
    end tell                                                                    
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you’re missing any command. I copied your script to Script Editor on my iMac, set values for theSubject, theBody, theAddress, theSender, and theAttachment, and ran it. It (a) successfully sent the message, and (b) I was able to view the message it sent in my Sent mailbox.

I tried this both with a known sender and with a random example.com sender. In both cases, it was saved in the default Sent box.

So the issue most likely lies elsewhere. Make sure that the value you’re currently using for theSender maps to an account in Mail that saves sent messages. (If it’s an IMAP account, it may be saving sent messages on the server, and server behavior may be affecting what you see.)

If that doesn’t work, set up some test values for all of the variables in the script except theAddress (using example.com for theSender), and include those (except theAddress) in your question. (If you can use example.com for theAddress, too, do that, but some servers will simply refuse the message immediately, which makes it worthless for testing this particular case.)

Note that you have an error that does not change this behavior; you have “visible” misspelled as “visibile”. However, I tried it both ways and in both cases the outgoing message does get stored in the appropriate Sent box.

Comment: thanks a lot. First for catching the misspell. Second for the potential resolution. I shall look IMAP setup, server setting, and try your method. And nice to have your confirmation my commands are good to save a copy. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after you send the message...

```
set accountReference to first account whose name = "my account name"
synchronize with accountReference
```